# Updated Kubuntu 15.04 today and now no KDE menu, I can start things from terminal if I remember their name

Tags: updates, kubuntu, kde

For example I can type dolphin in the terminal, and my session starts up with my fav apps, but I have no KDE start menu and no bar down th ebottom of my screen, I can alt-tab through open apps. alt- F2 gives me the command line widget but nought works there...

I've got muon package manager running (I assume it's some failure in installing or configuration) but it's saying there's nought to upgrade.

what do I do to isolate the issue?

TIA

And in trying to get kmenuedit going from the terminal and I get the following:

> Application: KDE Menu Editor (kmenuedit), signal: Segmentation fault
> Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
> [Current thread is 1 (Thread 0x7f78d9506800 (LWP 3864))]

Thread 2 (Thread 0x7f78c63bf700 (LWP 3865)):

## 0  0x00007f78d8fb88dd in poll () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:81

## 1  0x00007f78cfbd1b72 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1

## 2  0x00007f78cfbd364f in xcb_wait_for_event () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1

## 3  0x00007f78c82e3099 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so

## 4  0x00007f78d57d1b0e in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5

## 5  0x00007f78d52086aa in start_thread (arg=0x7f78c63bf700) at pthread_create.c:333

## 6  0x00007f78d8fc3eed in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:109

Thread 1 (Thread 0x7f78d9506800 (LWP 3864)):
[KCrash Handler]

## 6  0x00007f78d590ff5c in QDataStream::operator>>(int&) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5

## 7  0x00007f78d774ba25 in KServiceGroupFactory::KServiceGroupFactory() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libKF5Service.so.5

## 8  0x00007f78d774bba2 in KServiceGroupFactory::self() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libKF5Service.so.5

## 9  0x00007f78d77470c0 in KServiceGroup::root() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libKF5Service.so.5

## 10 0x00007f78d92aa526 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkdeinit5_kmenuedit.so

## 11 0x00007f78d92ab31f in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkdeinit5_kmenuedit.so

## 12 0x00007f78d92b31b3 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkdeinit5_kmenuedit.so

## 13 0x00007f78d92b359c in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkdeinit5_kmenuedit.so

## 14 0x00007f78d929f249 in kdemain () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkdeinit5_kmenuedit.so

## 15 0x00007f78d8edda40 in __libc_start_main (main=0x400720 , argc=1, argv=0x7fffe39da4b8, init=, fini=, rtld_fini=, stack_end=0x7fffe39da4a8) at libc-start.c:289

## 16 0x0000000000400759 in _start ()

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are running plasma 5 (check at login if you are running a different environment or window manager) and have your screen resolution correct (i.e. no screen scrolling), right click your desktop and unlock elements.
Right click desktop again and choose add panel -> default panel
You should now have a panel complete with clock, tray, task manager and kickoff (the menu).